# Recursive function analysis

Tags: recursion, recurrence

I'm trying to analyze the performance a recursive program I wrote.

The basic code is

```
Cost(x)
{
1 + MIN(Cost(x-1), Cost(x-2), Cost(x-3))
}
```

I want to write a recurrence relation for the number of calls made to Cost(). How would I start this?

Something like `T(x) = T(x/2)`. But I don't think that's right

Edit: I can represent this as a tree with a branching factor of 3 for each of the 3 recursive calls to Cost(). So would it would more accurately be `T(x) = T(x/3)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of calls made to Cost() would be:

```
C(x) = 1 + C(x-1) + C(x-2) + C(x-3)
```

So, for an input `x`, Cost() was called once plus the amount of times it was called for `x-1`, `x-2`, and `x-3`. This is assuming that your solution does not use memoization. The recurrence relation is not pretty: [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T(x)+%3D+1+%2B+T(x-1)+%2B+T(x-2)+%2B+T(x-3)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T%28x%29%20=%201%20%2b%20T%28x-1%29%20%2b%20T%28x-2%29%20%2b%20T%28x-3%29)

Using memoization, however, your "number of calls" becomes `C(x) = x` because you only need to evaluate `C(i)` once for all `i` between `0` and `x`. (Might be `C(x) = x + 1`, depending on your initial conditions)

Answer (score 0):

You really did write a recursive solution ?( i hope its a assignment to compare against linear iteration )

i think

```
T(X) = T(X-1)+T(X-2)+T(X-3)+C
C is small constant
```

Comment: Can you please explain the intuition behind that?